# How many SDR’s does the family of subsets $(A_1,...,A_{15})$ of the set $\{1, 2, ..., 15\}$ defined by $A_i = \{1, 2, ..., 15\}-\{i\}$ have?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

Let $(A_1,...,A_{15})$ be the family of subsets of the set $\{1, 2, ..., 15\}$ defined by
$A_i = \{1, 2, ..., 15\}-\{i\}$. How many SDR’s does this family have?

I know a SDR is of the form $(a_1,...,a_{15})$ where $a_i\in A_1$, all $a_i$ are distinct, and $1\leq a_i\leq 15$. I then noted that the cardinality of all $A_i$ is $|A_i|=14$. Thus, we see that the number of options $a_1$ has is $14$. If $a_1=2$, then $a_2$ has $14$ options too, but if $a_1\neq 2$, then $a_2$ has $13$. We can continue this argument to show that $a_3$ has $13$ or $12$ options, $a_4$ has $12$ or $11$ options, $\dots$ , and $a_{15}$ has $1$ option. Thus, the number of SDRs is
$$|\text{SDR}|=14\cdot(14+13)\cdot(13+12)\cdot(12+11)\cdot(11+10)\cdot(10+9)\cdot(9+8)\cdot(8+7)\cdot(7+6)\cdot(6+5)\cdot(5+4)\cdot(4+3)\cdot(3+2)\cdot(2+1)\cdot1$$
Does this look alright?

Comment: 1) Try for small values of "15", see if that works out. 2) Your answer is greater than $14! \times 2^{13} >> 15!$, so that's unlikely to be correct. 3) You might want to define what an SDR is. 4) Your terminology isn't quite standard, e.g. you seem to have an ordered set, but then you're calling it a subset. There is 1 subset of the set $ \{1, ..., 15 \}$ that has 15 elements in it.

Comment: do you think another way to approach this would be to find all the sequences of $\{1,...,15\}$ in which no number is in its original position? I.e. the derangement of 15 $d_{15}= 481066515734$

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes: your SDRs are precisely the derangements of $[15]$.